# Is there a complete list of iTunes Radio Featured Stations?

Tags: itunes-radio

iTunes Radio shows featured stations at the top of iTunes Radio. These are regularly updated and thus 'bumping' older featured stations. Some of these stations can still be accessed through the add station button. However some cannot be accessed except through an iTunes url that someone has shared.

For example here is the text of a tweet sent with a link to an old iTunes Radio featured station that I can't find through the add station button.

> Tune in to Music Heard at WWDC on iTunes Radio:
>   https://t.co/a5xbTAAI8m

Is there a list of links to old iTunes Radio featured stations?

Comment: I found the WWDC station! https://itunes.apple.com/us/station/idra.634968367

Comment: Old iTunes Radio features stations…as in from your history? Your question is really unclear…

Comment: @daviesgeek iTunes Radio shows featured radio stations that are updated regularly however there are only so many spots in the featured station listing, thus some stations get 'bumped' and there is no way to find them unless you have a link to the station that someone has shared.

Comment: @daviesgeek I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a list and it is by no means complete. Here are the 'hidden' stations that don't even show up in the search results when adding a station.

- [Pop Hits Summer Songs @iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/station/idra.634428421)
- [Music Heard at WWDC](https://itunes.apple.com/us/station/idra.634968367)

The rest are listed on my blog here:
http://stevemoser.org/blog/2013/09/21/hidden-itunes-radio-stations/

Comment: There's also a good (incomplete) official list here (takes you to iTunes): https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewMultiRoom?fcId=703990086